# How to prevent notifications of old Messages when I log into my Mac?

Tags: mac, messages

I use Messages on my Mac as well as my iPhone.

Whenever I log into my Mac, notifications pop up for each Message I've received since the last time I logged in, even though I've already checked them on my iPhone.

**How can I prevent this?**

I like having new message notifications appear, but it's annoying to see the whole day's message history every time I log in..!

Comment: Have you turned on power nap? This might help it realize the messages were already read. Support guide here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204032

Comment: Thanks John, it seems like that could work.  I've just enabled it on my machine, so we'll see what happens..!

Comment: Sounds good, let me know if it works or not (I can keep digging for you).

Comment: Hey @JohnRamos..! Power Nap did the trick.  I'm no longer seeing loads of message notifications when I log into my macbook..!  Thanks..!  Please post your solution as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad I could help! I posted my tip as an answer.

Comment: I've had this problem for years on all my machines.  Is there still no good answer?  Even if Power Nap fixes it, wouldn't that only help if the machine is sleeping?  What if it is turned off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power Nap, a feature of MacBooks that enables them to do more when they are asleep (like back up to iCloud/Time Capsule, check emails, and check iMessage) will allow your Mac to stop showing messages you've already read when you open your computer.  Here is [Apple's support guide on turning on Power Nap.](http://www.support.apple.com/en-us/HT204032)

Comment: Oh no... After almost 2 weeks, the notifications are back..! I've verified that Power Nap is still enabled.  Any other ideas?

Comment: @BizzyBob That's unfortunate! Hmm. Do you have power nap turned on for both battery power and plugged-in states? Check in System Preferences -> Energy Saver under both the Battery and Power Adapter tabs.

Comment: Yes, it is enabled for both.

Comment: @BizzyBob do you have Read Receipts off or on on your iPhone?

Comment: Read receipts are off. But that shouldn't really matter, would it?

Comment: @BizzyBob It shouldn't. Just thinking that maybe turning off read receipts goes further and disables your iPhone/Mac knowing if you read the message or not?